# Is there a way to register as a developer to Amazon's SP-API using a Vendor account?

Tags: amazon-mws

I'd like to register as a developer to the new Selling Partner API (SP-API) by Amazon.
This [doc](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#registering-as-a-developer) says I can do so using Seller Central, but I have a Vendor account, and therefore I need to use the Vendor Central.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can find everything you need in the [Selling Partner API Developer Guide for Vendors](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuideForVendors.md). In particular, the answer to your question is under the section ["Registering as a developer"](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuideForVendors.md#registering-as-a-developer).